# jquery form selector not working when form dynamically loads with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm banging my head on this for half a day.

I want to prevent submitting a form, so I can use ajax to submit it, but can't get the selectors to work.

My markup is this:

```
<div class="my_cart">
<ul>
<li>
<form action="/cart/remove_item" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="eb0d73613fd555ed3dc24d3877447fc7">
<input type="submit" name="foofoo" value="*">
</form>
</li>
<li>London</li>
<li class="crossed_price">46.00</li>
<li class="discount_price">free</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>
<form action="/cart/remove_item" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="71d2b4c973728137ec1905264be464b8">
<input type="submit" name="foofoo" value="*">
</form>
</li>
<li>Paris</li>
<li class="price">59.00</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the JS is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("Hello"); // this is to see if the function is triggered on page load. it is.
$("div.my_cart form").submit(function() { 
  alert ("no go");
  return false;
})
});
```

To my understanding, `$("div.my_cart form")` is supposed to catch **all** forms under **any** div whose class is "my_cart" but it doesn't seem to be working, and the form gets submitted as usual.

It's not a browser issue, as I've tested it on several browsers (Chrome, FF, Safari).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your html is invalid the `input` closing tags are missing... and by the way your code seems work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8RtML/

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. It's working for me somewhere else, where the input tags are not closed.
Also, the form is created using Codeigniter form helper. I'm guessing they got it right.

Comment: So I did get it right. But for some reason it's not working. Any ideas how to debug it? The `alert("Hello")` is working.

Comment: Is your `my_cart` div is in the page from the begining. Or do you load it dynamically with ajax? And which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I was just about to edit my question to add this info...
After you confirmed to me my selector syntax was OK, I realised it's not a selectors issue after all. You are quite right. `my_cart` is loaded dynamically with ajax. So how do I refer to the form within it?

Comment: If you are using jquery 1.7. or grater you can use it like `$("div.my_cart form").on("submit", function () {
        alert("no go");
        return false;
    })`

Comment: Yeah you are right about the correct syntax. I've updated my answer with it. And with that `.on("submit", "div.my_cart form", function () {` also should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code inside the `$(document).ready(function() {` only runs once when the DOM is loaded. If you load additional parts of your page with AJAX this method won't fire it again.

So because you are dynamically adding `my_cart` the event subsciption won't work in the document ready event.

You need to use the jQuery [on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to subscribe on events of dynamically added elements:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Hello");
    $(document).on("submit", "div.my_cart form", function () {
        alert("no go");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks again. :-) I edited the question since it really is about ajax and not only jquery selectors...

Comment: And just a thought: do you think it's good practice to always use `$(document).on("submit", "form-selector", function ()` instead of `$("form-selector").submit(function()`?

Comment: The `submit` method is a shortcut for `.on('submit', handler)`. The difference is there on which element do use it: eg. with `$(document)` you attach your handler globally to the whole docuemnt. With `$("form-selector").on("submit", )` you attach it on a much smaller parts of the DOM (so it has performance benefits) but if the DOM element is dynamically loaded you cannot use that.